# Executing JS function immediately in plain JS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm attempting to learn to use three.js. I don't know much JS but I figured I'd pick it up as I went along. I'm having difficulty getting the following two things to work together:

fire.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fire.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" href="js/fire.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" href="js/three.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="fire()"></body>

</html>
```

js/fire.js:

```
function fire() {
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    camera.position.z = 5;

    var box_geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
    var box_material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh(box_geometry, box_material);

    scene.add(cube);

    var animate = function() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
        cube.rotation.y -= 0.01;

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };

    animate();
}
```

I'm getting an undefined reference error that fire() doesn't exist when I attempt to use onload (I don't know what the little options contained within tags are called).

I am using Python's SimpleHTTPServer (`python -m SimpleHTTPServer`) to host this code locally. I'm not sure if this is known to have any issues. I managed to get [this](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/introduction/Creating-a-scene) code to work using the same setup, so it seems that my issue lies in figuring out how best to use JS without actually embedding it in my HTML since that seems cleanest.

I also ran fire.js through jslint to make sure I didn't have any syntax errors and it looks okay. (feel free to check my work).

So, I'm at a loss. How do I make these two cooperate? (Preferably using plain JavaScript, just for the moment)

Comment: You can always take a look at IIFEs (Immediately Invoked Function Expressions): http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/an-introduction-to-iffes-immediately-invoked-function-expressions.html

Comment: But fire should not be able to reference `THREE` unless you put it after three.js. (fire.js after three.js in your head) Maybe inspect that undefined reference error a bit closer.

Comment: Verify you are not getting a 404 / not found error when loading `fire.js`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `src` attribute not `href` for referencing external JavaScript files:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fire.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fire.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/three.js"></script>
</head>
```

For future reference, you can use the Network tab (in Chrome's Developer Tools) to verify the external file is actually getting loaded correctly.

Comment: Ah! The `src` tags worked. Thank you! Also, that's really neat, I'm still getting used to the developer console. I'll have to dig around there and learn to use that effectively. Thank you again!